# MySQL database to Excel (1 table to 1 worksheet)

Tags: mysql, excel, export, export-to-excel

How to export MySQL database to excel document that 1 table in database is saved to 1 worksheet in xls document.

I am using Navicat, MySQL Maestro and SQLyog and all of them export one table per document.

Thank You

Comment: You may find you need to write a small program to do this, using the language of your choice.

Comment: i know, i wrote some backup scripts in php with some cron jobs but right now i don't have time for writing export to csv that is why i have all those program in 2011 :) feels more like 1911 with this export :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that in Navicat you can use export all tables from database to excel if you select "Excel file (*.xls)" instead of "Excel spreadsheet (*.xls)" and then for every table in your database add path to the same excel file :)